# How do the Amazons like Wonder Woman avoid extinction if they live in an island with no men?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman, wonder-woman-2017

When Wonder Woman first met Steve on the island, she was intrigued by the sight of a man. That shows how deprived the Amazons women were when it comes to men.

The island where the Amazons live has no men. How do they avoid extinction if they do not get married and produce babies?

Comment: Please separate this question into two parts as what you're asking are distinct things.

Comment: @Mooz, I asked this question after watching the latest movie.

Comment: Also, they are virtually immortal, so the fact that they've encountered no people is why they haven't gone extinct.

Comment: <sass>Also, they are strong independent women who need no men</sass>

Comment: @Mooz, I am sure there are many strong independent women who choose to be single. However, no matter how strong, no woman can get pregnant without the help from a man.

Comment: @Adamant, I took away that question on Mooz's request to break it into separate questions.

Comment: Related question from sister site :[How is Themiscyra populated?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75844/how-is-themiscyra-populated)

Comment: You're not familiar with Greek mythology? Lots of women getting pregnant from gods in animal form, and of course Athena herself being born from the forehead of Zeus. (I'm always baffled by people demanding scientific realism from superhero films, but demanding it from the mythlogical source material is even more fruitless)

Comment: @user486818 You seem to be assuming that the Amazons are human. They are not human, they are immortal beings created by the gods and don't need to reproduce (although in some versions of their fictional history they do sometimes have children).

Comment: They have no sense of "deprivation" by the absence of men. It's  inadvertently sexist perspective. When Diana looks at Steve, she's intrigued by the novelty of his gender. She *knows* what a man is but has never seen one. She nor any of the other Amazons view him as something they've been "deprived" of. Steve and Diana's bond is one of duty and selflessness. Any sexual or "romantic" story arcs aren't pursued. Amazons are often confused for lesbians and heterosexual men seem unable to comprehend how *any* woman may not "miss" men. https://www.britannica.com/topic/Amazon-Greek-mythology

Comment: For what it is worth, you don't need to get married to produce babies.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the [DC wiki](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Paradise_Island), the Amazons are immortal beings that were created to teach men the virtues of peace and love.

So, at least in terms of the main comic continuity, the Amazons are indeed immortal.

In the terms of the movie, we see ample evidence of Amazon immortality as Diana herself is seen in modern day Paris remembering her days in World War One.

Comment: However in the movie it was not confirmed they are immortal. Perhaps they just have a very, very, very long lifespan.

Comment: You make a good point Neow, however we can come to the conclusion that they are immortal quite comfortably.  The lack of men means that reproduction was not an option.  So they are either immortal or their lifespans are incredibly long (which would still serve to answer the question to some extent).  Whilst the movie took A LOT of liberties with the source material, there is no reason to assume that they would change the characteristic of Amazons being immortal.

Comment: "The lack of men means that reproduction was not an option" : Parthenogenesis is always an option

Comment: Human parthenogenesis is not really much of an option.  It is more common is less complex organisms (and Chanseys).  Also, why would a sexually dimorphic species spontaneously develop parthenogenesis?

Comment: @MagikarpMaster Gods? Magic? The story demands it? Comic book logic? The Amazons were specifically stated to originate from a distinct act of deific creation.  The Amazons are not clearly either a species or sexually dimorphic. A different creation act would suggest they need not be the same species as humans, and the Amazons themselves were not created as dimorphic. And apparent immortality would throw certain suspicions on being a "species" itself.

Comment: If it's suggested in the movies that they are immortal. It is explicit in the comics, and the movies are based on the comics. That suggests, but doesn't prove, that they are immortal in the movies. But, barring anything explicit in the movie, that's the best information we have right now.

Comment: I will also throw in Diana's fascination with babies as evidence that they are not common in Themyscira. So at least the typical way to procreate is likely not practiced in Themyscira.

Comment: @MagikarpMaster Sexually dimorphic vertebrates -- specifically, [lizards and snakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenogenesis_in_squamata) -- have evolved parthenogenesis. So it can happen.

Comment: @Marq I was unaware of that.  That is very interesting, but the parthenogenesis argument still does not hold here.  If the Amazons did indeed reproduce via parthenogenesis, then there would not be the obvious genetic variance that we see in the Amazons.  The fact that there are Amazons of different races and builds, with different eye and hair colour, and different chin and earlobe shapes all point to the fact that they are not the product of parthenogenesis (parthenogenesis is essentially natural cloning as no new genetic material is introduced)

Comment: @MagikarpMaster,  I don't get the logic behind that claim at all.   How many different Amazons did you see?   Why can't there have been a hundred Amazons originally created with all different appearances and the rest by parthenogenesis?  If I were really playing devil's advocate,  I could cite the obvious "ethnicities" within the Amazon population even though they lived in a confined space for thousands of years as evidence ***against*** sexual reproduction and ***for*** cloning.

Comment: @ThePopMachine I get what you are saying, but hear me out.  If parthenogenesis is the way they reproduce, why is there exactly one of each of them?  It is not as if you immediately die after reproducing via parthenogenesis, so you would expect to see multiple versions of the same amazon.

Comment: They seem to live a long time, perhaps forever; but they can be killed by bullets as we see in the movie. Diana is no exception since she blocks bullets with her bracelets.

Answer (score 3):

There is only one child and none of the women seem to age.  We can assume the residents don't age. We can't tell if this once they reach maturity or if Diana is different in this way.

Comment: This is probably true…but could you provide some references from the film/comics?

Comment: Don't they age? Let's say most of the Amazons seems to look like they're in their 30s.  Antiope looks significantly older than the other Amazons - no disrespect - and is supposed to be the more experienced.

Comment: In the film, Diana is technically only created _in the form of a child_ by Zeus. (SPOILER) His intention is revealed to be that she is actually a weapon that he created specifically to destroy Ares, so she is not a child in the human sense, although she does mature into an adult version of herself  - the Amazon's in the film are immortal and also created by the Greek gods, quite likely they have retained the forms they were created with.

Answer (score 0):

It has always been my understanding that the Amazons, including Diana, are immortal as long as they stay on Paradise Island.  Diana's belt keeps her immortal off of the island.

Comment: Hello Joe, and welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Good answer, but it might be nice to add a source to this that differentiates it from the accepted answer.